# Getting error "ORA 00604 error occurred at recursive sql level 1 ORA 00103 no statement parsed"

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
Create Or replace procedure getMenuList
(
    Id in number default null, 
    Cv_1 out sys_REFCURSor
) 
As
Begin
    Open cv_1 for
    With applMenu (parentid, menuid, menuname, orderid, dbid, level) as ((
    Select a.parentid, a.menuid, a.name, a.orderid, a.dbid, 0 level from MenuData a where a.menuid= Id) 
    Union all
    Select a.parentid, a.menuid, a.name, a.orderid, a.dbid,level +1 from MenuData a, applMenu ab where a.menuid=ab.parentid start with ab.menuid = 1 connect by level <= 2)) 
    Select ab.parentid, ab.menuid, ab.menuname, ab.orderid, ab.dbid,ab.level from applMenu ab;
End;
```

This procedure got compiled successfully but getting error when I try to execute

Comment: This procedure got compiled successfully but getting error when I try to execute

Variable cv_1 refcursor; Execute getMenuList(1, :Cv_1); Print cv_1;

Getting error "ORA 00604 error occurred at recursive sql level 1 ORA 00103 no statement parsed"

Comment: Why tag SQL Server for an Oracle issue? Also [edit] any additional info directly into the question, not in comments.

Comment: I tried information in question itself, but it was showing error

Answer (score 0):

Parenthesis for the `WITH` clause was not correct (The extra closing bracket was there).

Please see if the following code resolves your issue.

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE GETMENULIST (
    ID     IN    NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
    CV_1   OUT   SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS 
BEGIN 
OPEN CV_1 for WITH APPLMENU (
    PARENTID,
    MENUID,
    MENUNAME,
    ORDERID,
    DBID,
    LEVEL
) AS 
 (SELECT A.PARENTID,
             A.MENUID,
             A.NAME,
             A.ORDERID,
             A.DBID,
             0 LEVEL
      FROM MENUDATA A
     WHERE A.MENUID = ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.PARENTID,
           A.MENUID,
           A.NAME,
           A.ORDERID,
           A.DBID,
           LEVEL + 1
      FROM MENUDATA   A,
           APPLMENU   AB
     WHERE A.MENUID = AB.PARENTID START WITH
        AB.MENUID = 1
    CONNECT BY
        LEVEL <= 2
)
Select
    AB.PARENTID,
    AB.MENUID,
    AB.MENUNAME,
    AB.ORDERID,
    AB.DBID,
    AB.LEVEL from
    APPLMENU AB;
END;
/
```

Comment: I have removed bracket, it's not working. i have used extra bracket for select statement before union